# How to delete all pages from a certain category

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

Is there a possibility or a special page, that provides following use case:

- I have several pages > 10 < 100 in a category
- Instead of separate page delete, it would be convenient to delete all pages in that category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are extensions to do bulk page deletes.

Look at:

- Nuke (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Nuke)
- DeleteBatch (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DeleteBatch)

Answer (score 4):

[Just to complete] If you are not syadmin or just don't want to install the Extensions, there is always [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) and [delete.py](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/delete.py).